# Error x-amzn-errortype: InvalidSignatureException on DELETE request to API gateway

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I am attempting to build a javascript application.
I am unable to get a DELETE request authenticated via IAM.

The API gateway delete route has been configured to use AWS_IAM authentication. Cognito user group has a role attached which grants access to invoke the delete route.

**I've signed the request using AWS.Signers.V4**

```
var httpRequest = new AWS.HttpRequest("https://bo5o2odxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/wrhprod/"+uri, "ap-south-1");

httpRequest.headers.host = "https://bo5o2odxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com";
httpRequest.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

httpRequest.method = method; 

var v4signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(httpRequest, "execute-api", true);
v4signer.addAuthorization(awsCredentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());
delete httpRequest.headers['host']
delete httpRequest.headers['X-Amz-User-Agent']
```

**I am using axios to send the delete request:**

```
axios.delete('/events/2017/1523502329582',
{ headers: httpRequest.headers})
.then(response => {
//success
})
.catch(error => {
//fail
});
```

**This is my request Header:**

```
:authority: bo5o2odxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
:method: DELETE
:path: /wrhprod/events/2017/1523502329582
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, /
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAIGIXC2II7KWVVUVA/20180413/ap-south-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=f1b12cf3c1a3693f259e2f0079231974d6de0e4225bca0af3754a32eecf95277
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/events
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
x-amz-date: 20180413T071741Z
x-amz-security-token: AgoGb3JpZ2luEAwaCmFwLXNvdXRoLTEigAIBwvwgU/vlYPZI1+XYbJUieH7lQB1XI32w08GaX0MjobxyfhFK7J3md5GaKlPdO3I+fqjYpBWOlrqNNllgjKTLZwNOx7SxrVq5T57qk27nq6kp1Y5nSDTy+wj6pHVbSmzRgrfqvOgsgWrU6NsB41taHLaN3sjQaneSC7/phQ3+UvdjQrEI7egI7TikiUs/DW6oQWMupW/75c9GEVnoA2RRdYmVqVh//OmbWdG6DMk09ritP6eLpUYvWHGrMNniGnT2Rj+3kbOgSst0JrKLwssOsO3lIm+iDxSk3NGoKRUX4iB/Lnv7XQnUaFoK2PC0DNyj9XnJVn0RXoXCPOOwPf9wKqwFCEAQABoMMTQ0MTUzMjMxNzA0Igwr7GTDa3MwS/6L7RIqiQU4WK45J//oxnc98LgRZOApKGYPyRfiDgd+LHG006GHDJTodDTysv1YIkLbOq6Da1d6ENpwdkW7h8OgtR4r+BoOPeP7h+vV55LJHexPGAGC8GKimK8iKFLjvyy1ArGWGb9FEbYtsJkjjxFZw2uZJ3ex3YWQk5UiBDkuJd8paU8rqSctcF/0SLFZyK77AndiLs7Ir3AwBvlQvOh+J3Q8MCfAuRLGOAT1VTYOMis/ZL7cczi1YRWK+7jlRdeoeQu/aP9Y07SbxRxzIh7YyhFBilLXUslRiyeKiehYK6ufI/czC2bDipegBmCAFiEff/PKvBinSUJRTkSJODmh6E25OVerbbSBgI1aCGj+b3bRiBiMwu+kIF77czK18jBfE5OeexKfh+r1w2puyYDwPgQMz9ki5BdQtHvzm0/p8W88+tPGNB0EO7E4TyWtfJ0HyLU6wgVpf4LB9YPDeUxoR8JdB+QLCXNDPdFEuWPQRgm4MgngAyHwVn+NnFsBk1U/GNHabWeX0k+PsxNn5LJ6u4RQCDP0YDsGrQmIO6DIrUWidBZ00XMeaJXWrsgHb/6qINijvg3sk1y9P7kxEZyfarotDEjqLRjpyUBufRfiCVccQ5bF0MeOxxMN4ZFC7mX7xtaSQKcmv2sG1uJus9d7yyd3phQ4FluiI77UE5CVx3bkdRlEObRXB/DyCv+gfk3VfouIchF8xNpMU1jmaHN5+rB0/lbTMxVmEX8qYc6UdZXIIWRm2spB2YwnacBhC0Q36CnCwU1hcRo7YhcminiCPQy6+7OrOTLLXKAenRjNIuPYGAaZQl1MgPMBwFpPGAdbrJG/iWleNf5fN+dettOD18VT8jrmdQ0jRM5N9OjEMJqvwdYF
```

**This is the AWS response header:**

```
content-length: 192
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 07:17:41 GMT
status: 403
x-amz-apigw-id: FRLvXEDeBcwFuLQ=
x-amzn-errortype: InvalidSignatureException
x-amzn-requestid: c0f040c3-3eea-11e8-bd7a-dd445896cd03
```

I've spent hours on this & have not found a solution, please let me know if I can supply any other information to help troubleshoot.

This same API was working using cognito as an API gateway authorizer, I switches to IAM so that I may have more fine grained control on the cognito users.

Comment: `delete httpRequest.headers['host']` and 
`delete httpRequest.headers['X-Amz-User-Agent']` ...why?  These are part of the `SignedHeaders`.  Deleting them would be *expected* to invalidate the signature.

Comment: I removed those headers because I was getting a CORS error on the OPTIONS method.

Request header field X-header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Your comment got me thinking. I can add the headers to the OPTIONS method in API gateway which should fix the problem. I will try this out a bit later & let you know if it fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot I was removing 'X-Amz-User-Agent' as I was getting a CORS error. I managed to get around that by adding it to the allowed headers in the OPTIONS method. Now the problem is chrome is not allowing me to set the 'host' header. It gives error 'Refused to set unsafe header "host"'. API gateway requests are not working without the host header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get AWS.Signers.V4 to work. From what I read, this API is not public yet.

I was able to get my APP working using a custom client to sign the request. It is available for download [Here](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/sigV4Client)